# Problem 8 from chapter 4 ("Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction") of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The following is problem 8 from chapter 4 ("Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction") of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis.

> Suppose $\{t_k\}$ is a collection of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Assume that 
>   $$
> \|T_kT^*_j\|\leq a_{k-j} 
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> \|T^*_kT_j\|\leq a^*_{k-j} 
> $$
>   for positive constants $\{a_n\}$ with the property that $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_n=A<\infty$. Then $S_N(f)$ converges as $N\rightarrow\infty$, for every $f\in H$, with $S_N=\sum_{-N}^{N}T_k$. Moreover, $T=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}S_N$ satisfies $\|T\|\leq A$

1.What does $a^*_{k-j}$ mean?

2.Could you please give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Maximiliano: Thank you for your answer, but could you please give me a more detailed explanation. I have found that this question is a generalization of exercise 23 in the same chapter, Perhaps it would be easier to solve or to help me with that problem.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I suspect the $a_n^*$ are just meant to be another sequence of constants, satisfying the same summability condition as the $a_n$.

Comment: Estimate $\lVert S_n (f) - S_m(f) \rVert ^2 = \langle S_n (f) - S_m(f) , S_n (f) - S_m(f) \rangle $

Comment: I am almost certain this is a printing error. The problem should read $\lVert T_k T_j^* \rVert \leq a_{k-j}^2$, and similarly for the other expression. This is the Cotlar-Stein lemma.

The solution to this problem bears no relation to the other exercise, that is the orthogonal case. For that exercise it is best to show that the operators have orthogonal ranges and orthogonal "domains" (where the domain is $N(t)^\perp$) then look at the sum, as @Maximiliano said.